# mismatched input '.' expecting EOF (... from cpe where ip=10.240[.]...)">

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a table in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE scr.cpe (
    ...     ip text PRIMARY KEY,
    ...     cpe frozen<map<text, frozen<list<text>>>>
    ... ) ;
```

I am trying to execute this statement

```
cql_insert = SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO cpe (ip, cpe) VALUES (%s, %s)")
my_dict = dict()
my_dict['o']=["Linux"]
session.execute(cql_insert, ("10.240.165.151 ", my_dict))
string="10.240.165.151"
session.execute('SELECT cpe from cpe where ip='+string) #error here
```

Which throws this error

```
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:36 mismatched input '.' expecting EOF (... from cpe where ivp=10.240[.]...)">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `string="'10.240.165.151'"` (extra quotes)

Comment: it works, thanks! But why the need for the extra quotes?

Comment: SQL requires them.  The original quotes will be stripped off, they are only used when inputting literal text into python.